# Is it feasible to use an iPad that supports Apple Pencil 2nd Generation without internet?

Tags: ipad, network, wifi, security, ipados

I need an iPad to manage the tons of note-taking and reading I have to do.

But I don't want any access to *wireless* internet to keep my *bad videos* addiction under control.

I asked a question [here](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/773865/Is+is+advisable+to+remove+wifi+antennas?permalink=answer-773947#answer773947) - got to know it is pointless messing with the electronics, so I have replaced WiFi with cable only internet at my place.

I have never owned any Apple device before (and it was news to me that changing batteries could brick your iPhone) - so before I buy iPad Air 5th gen or the 11" Pro - I want to know whether the following workflow is feasible:

1. use RJ45 adapter to load the software and books (some PDFs given by TAs/Professors, which are not available on any of the paid stores, I can only download if form uni sharepoint folder).
2. study/note offline for long periods (daily 9 hours is a habit).
3. reconnect to internet only when a subject is complete - via RJ45 - to sync notes and download next ones.

**Summary:** Is it feasible to use an M1 iPad without internet for 2-3 months, *will the OS give problems if it can't phone home for that much time*?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You are aking two questions - can you use an iPad without internet for a long time - answer  is yes. A separate question is can you just use ethernet and no wifi.

Comment: Would using the iPad's ability to whitelist/blacklist websites, and to block known adult sites be sufficient? You could even get someone else to set this up, requiring an additional passcode to change the settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently have taken an interest myself in seeing how much an iPad can be isolated from the internet while still being useful for my daily tasks. What you're wanting to do should definitely be feasible.

> 1 Use RJ45 adapter to load the software and books (some PDFs given by TAs/Professors, which are not available on any of the paid stores, I can only download if form uni sharepoint folder).

> 3 reconnect to internet only when a subject is complete - via RJ45 - to sync notes and download next ones.

You can buy an adapter that goes from either Lightning or USB-C to RJ-45. I do this myself sometimes and it works great.

> 2. study/note offline for long periods (daily 9 hours is a habit).

You can use the device offline however long you want. There's a number of apps, including Notes and Pages made by Apple, that do not need an internet connection after being downloaded to use them.

Comment: Can't upvote, but thanks for the answer.