# How long can an (M1 or greater) iPad run without internet?

Tags: ipad, network, cellular-data

I asked a question [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/464513/505971) - mostly centered around coping with addiction.

But I have been reading various sources and I came to know that daily internet might be required on any modern computing device for things like:

1. Synchronizing clock with NTP
2. getting some cryptographic tokens which expire after some time like HTTP headers
3. making sure user still has access to *paid* features in an app beyond a certain date

... and many more.

So - have there been any experiments/studies/experiences on how long an M1 or newer iPad can run without internet before it taps out? By tap out I mean becoming practically useless: either being unable to turn on or just doing one of its enterprise walled-garden shenanigans.

Comment: How does this differ from your other question?

Comment: @nohillside I guess you're correct - please give me 3-4 hours, if I am unable to improve it, I will delete it

Comment: @nohillside this is more specific, more Google/SEO friendly, whereas the previous one was more centered around my personal issues this one talks about the device's nature. Like others said the Rj45 angle was a question in itself

Comment: On a very basic level modern iOS devices want to connect to the network. However if you turn off WiFi and Bluetooth there is no reason you should not be able to go indefinitely without a network connection. Note that iPadOS may start to bug you at some point to connect to the internet but you *should* be able to just cancel those dialog boxes. Personally I have had an iOS device disconnected from the internet for *months* using it just as a glorified iPod with no issues. This may be one of those, "try it and see" kind of things.